# QBitArray to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

When we create a text file with this text "ali ata bak", and we use this file as input for the program. The code is running normally. But when we enter "1111111111111111111111" this text in the textfile, Code isnt running expected. So What is the problem?

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QBitArray>
#include <QByteRef>
#include <QFile>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <QTextStream>

// Buffer Size #num of KB's
#define BUFFER_SIZE_KB 1

// Do not change !!
#define BUFFER_SIZE_BYTE BUFFER_SIZE_KB*1024
#define BUFFER_SIZE_BIT  BUFFER_SIZE_BYTE*8

using namespace std;


QBitArray bytesToBits(QByteArray bytes) {
    QBitArray bits(bytes.count()*8);
    // Convert from QByteArray to QBitArray
    for(int i=0; i<bytes.count(); ++i)
        for(int b=0; b<8; ++b)
            bits.setBit(i*8+b, bytes.at(i)&(1<<b));
    return bits;
}


QByteArray bitsToBytes(QBitArray bits) {
    QByteArray bytes;
    bytes.resize(bits.count()/8);
    // Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
    for(int b=0; b<bits.count(); ++b)
        bytes[b/8] = ( bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(b%8)));
    return bytes;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString inFilename;
    QString outFilename;
    QTextStream qtin(stdin);


    cout << "Filename : ";
    qtin >> inFilename;
    outFilename.append("_");
    outFilename.append(inFilename);

    QFile infile(inFilename);
    if (!infile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        cout << "\nFile cant opened\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    QFile outfile(outFilename);
    if (!outfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        cout << "\nFile cant opened\n";
        system("pause");
        return 2;
    }

    QByteArray bytes, bytes2;
    QBitArray bits;


    while ((bytes = infile.read(BUFFER_SIZE_BYTE)) >0 ) {

        bits = bytesToBits(bytes);
        bytes2 = bitsToBytes(bits);// PROBLEM IS HERE
        outfile.write(bytes2);

    }

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();
    cout << "Finished\n";
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unexpected"? Please describe what you are seeing and what you were expecting.

Comment: output file must be same with input but the file that has text "11111" not same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialization problem.

```
QByteArray bitsToBytes(QBitArray bits) {
    QByteArray bytes;
    bytes.resize(bits.count()/8+1);
    bytes.fill(0);
    // Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
    for(int b=0; b<bits.count(); ++b)
        bytes[b/8] = ( bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(b%8)));
    return bytes;
}
```

this produces the right answer

Comment: Also a note: `while ((bytes = infile.read(BUFFER_SIZE_BYTE)) >0 )` is incorrect, comparing q QByteArray with an int doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Explicit null termination is unnecessary with QByteArray.

Comment: Also a note: output file size grow up 1 byte with this solution

Comment: I noticed that QbitArray is actually backed by a QByteArray. Might be able to exploit this to arrive at a better solution.

Comment: Please resize without `+1`

Answer (score 1):

```
QByteArray bitsToBytes(const QBitArray& bits)
{
    QByteArray bytes;
    QDataStream stream(&bytes, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream << bits;
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: This seems to add "\x00\x00\x00\b" at the front to `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

```
QBitArray bits(8);

// The deep copy of bits
QByteArray bytes(bits.bits(), bits.count() / 8); 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The bits are not copied
QByteArray bytes = QByteArray::fromRawData(bits.bits(), bits.count() / 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to read about endianness from the Wikipedia  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers from iloahz, solve the problem of output file size grow up 1 byte.

```cpp
QByteArray bitsToBytes(QBitArray bits) {
    QByteArray bytes;
    bytes.resize(bits.count() / 8 + ((bits.count() % 8)? 1: 0));
    bytes.fill(0x00);
    // Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
    for(int b = 0; b < bits.count(); ++b)
        bytes[b / 8] = (bytes.at(b / 8) | ((bits[b]? 1: 0) << (b % 8)));
    return bytes;
}
```